# HTML to type bar above a number(vinculam symbol)

Tags: html

I am a Blogger. It is very necessary for me to write bar above numbers. I googled it several times. But there was no articles about this. Most of the articles are discussing about putting bar above letters(texts). That didn't worked for numbers. For example in this mathforum [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20180116063114/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57579.html) they added a bar above numbers  several times. I tried to put bar above 67 using `67x&#772;` But this only showed bar  above 7, and this bar above 7 was not legible. Is it only possible with Mathjax? How can I write bar above numbers for blogger?

Comment: It's very hard to imagine a solution that works for text but not for numbers. Can you show an example?

Comment: Please provide examples (both code and rendered characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Most of the articles are discussing about putting bar above letters(texts). That didn't worked for numbers.

I'm surprised by this statement. Here below is a quick example I've set up. You can see that I'm able to place a bar above the text that is wrapped within a `<span class="putBar">...</span>` element. You have take in mind that the text may appear close of each other. You can manipulate it by using `line-height` property on the `<p>` element.

```css
span.putBar {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <p>
    lorum ipsum dolor rem. Trying to get a bar above this word <span class="putBar">barAboveMe</span> and this number <span class="putBar">123</span> or that number <span class="putBar">123456789</span> This one shouldn't get a bar above it: noBarAboveMe.
    </p>
</article>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually I am not a web designer. That is why I choosed blogger as blogging platform. I don't know CSS. But I will spent some time to study CSS. Also it was my first question on stack overflow. However thank you for criticising me. It prompted me for some self introspection(for studying CSS). The code  is working superb.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try css property.  text-decoration: overline;

```html
Take a look <span style="text-decoration:overline;">Sample</span>.Hope it helps
```